# Can't get web.config transform to work

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config

I have an ASP.Net application. I created the transforms for the Web.config file to produce Web.Debug.config and Web.Release.config. Unfortunately, I can't get the code to read these transforms at run time. Here's a snippet of the code that's reading the .config file:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Logger logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

        string config = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Configuration"];
        Label1.Text = string.Format("Configuration application string = \"{0}\"", config);
```

Here is a snippet from the original Web.config file:

```
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="Configuration" value="Default"/>
  </appSettings>
```

Here's the corresponding snippet from the Web.Release.config file:

```
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
  <appSettings xdt:Transform="Replace">
    <add key="Configuration" value="Release"/>
  </appSettings>
```

When I preview the transform, all is good (i.e., I see that the value of "Configuration" is "Release"). However, when I build, publish, and run it, I get the default value.

I read elsewhere that the transforms don't work on the build but rather on the publish, but I'm publishing to C:\inetpub\wwwroot. And when I look at the Web.config file there it does say "Release". Why isn't it showing up when I run my program? (This is Windows 7 Professional and VS2013.)

Comment: See this site: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd465318(v=vs.100).aspx

I appears you're missing the xdt:Locator="Match(key)

Comment: I read that, but I don't think you need Locator if you're doing a full Replace. Upon further investigation I think it may have something to do with IIS?